# Know it all client and a wife that stirs the pot. Gun shy of not getting paid and history of clients being A CHRONIC SUE COUPLE

Tags: contracts, difficult-client, payments, late-payment, trust

I’m a contractor and I’m feeling like I’m going to be fired for doing a job that they asked me to do that isn’t part of my bid or job. They are threatening not to pay me. I’m sought out by clients that have heard about my work and loyalty all over Washington state. I’ve lost their trust. What do people recommend I do moving forward? Unfortunately it’s a cash job from a referral from a subcontractor.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you never had their trust to begin with. It sounds like they were looking for a reason to not pay.

First off, it is important to realize that no matter how good you are, there are some people who can never be satisfied. Some clients are not worth keeping. This is why you need a "contract termination" clause in the contract saying that you can cancel the contract and return their money for any reason that you need.

No matter how much cash is involved, it can be cheaper to give the cash back and tell them to find someone else. Instead of you being fired, you fire them.

Your peace of mind may be more valuable than any amount of cash from any client. When you can walk away from tens or hundreds of thousands in order to keep your peace of mind, it is possible to make much more with better clients. With peace of mind, you can find much better clients (and you can be much better able to get any short term loan needed to cover the hiccup in the cash flow).